# Error while trying to convert the String format dateTime into DateTime format in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to convert the date time in the string format to DateTime but its showing **"FormatException (FormatException: Trying to read dd from MONDAY at position 0)"**

```
safePrint(Intl.withLocale(
              'en',
              () => new DateFormat("dd, EEE MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss \'GMT\'")
                  .parse(batch_timing[j])));

          print(new DateFormat('dd, EEE MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss \'GMT\'')
              .parse(batch_timing[j]));
```

Note : date format is **"Mon, 05 Sep 2022 10:00:00 GMT"**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a correction in converting :

check the below

```
 String mDate ="Mon, 05 Sep 2022 10:00:00 GMT";

    print(DateFormat('EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss \'GMT\'')
              .parse(mDate));
```

you have to use `EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss \'GMT\''`  instead of `dd, EEE MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss \'GMT\''`